# Why RAFT protocol rejects RequestVote with lower term?

Tags: consensus, raft

In raft every node rejects any request with term number lower than it's own. But why do we need this for RequestVote rpc? If **Leader Completeness Property** holds, then node can vote for this candidate, right? So why reject request? I can't come up with example, where without this additional check when receiving RequestVote we can lose our consistency, safety, etc.

Maybe someone can help pls?

Answer (score 1):

A candidate with lower term in RequestVote RPC has **a log that could be not up to date** with other nodes because a leader could be elected in a higher term and already replicated an entry to a majority of servers.

If this candidate is elected leader, the rules of raft cause this leader to not be able to do anything for safety reasons. Its RPCs will be rejected by other servers due to lower term.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are these reasons.

1. Term in Raft is monotonically increasing. All requests from previous terms are requests made based on stale state and will only be rejected and returned with the current term and leader information.
2. Any elected leader must have all committed logs before the election, a candidate from the previous term is unlikely to have all committed logs since it won't have any committed logs from the current term.